# destructure of object returned by array.find

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array messages

```
[{id:1, userId:'123',test:'hello'},{id:2, userId:'124',test:'world'}]
```

And another array members

```
[{id:'123',firstName:'sam',lastName:'rest', email:'something@a.com'},
 {id:'124',firstName:'tim',lastName:'best', email:'abc@a.com'}]
```

And I want to return below array

```
[{messageId:1, userId:'123',test:'hello', fullName:'sam rest', email:'something@a.com'},
 {messageId:2, userId:'124',test:'world', fullName:'sam best', email:'abc@a.com'}]
```

I tried to do a map on first array followed by a find on the second array, but I'm not able to figure out how to modify the keys of the resultant found item. Below is where I got to

```
return messages.map((message) => ({
   ...message,
   messageId: message.id,
   ...members.find((member) => member.id === message.userId),
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me @Nikhil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure out the first name, last name, and test and then insert those destructed arguments during your map, as follows:

```js
const messages = [{id:1, userId:'123',test:'hello'},{id:2, userId:'124',test:'world'}];

const members = [{id:'123',firstName:'sam',lastName:'rest', email:'something@a.com'},
 {id:'124',firstName:'tim',lastName:'best', email:'abc@a.com'}];
 
 const merged = messages.map(message => {
   const { firstName, lastName, email, id } = members.find(({ id }) => id === message.userId);
   const fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
   return {
     messageId: message.id,
     userId: id,
     test: message.test,
     fullName,
     email
   }
 });
 
 console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Nice use of destructuring but this code throws an error if a member doesn't exist (though unlikely in OP's scenario).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create new properties/keys and use values from the found member. To avoid inserting `undefined` values, you can check if a member exists before adding the values.

```js
const messages = [{id:1, userId:'123',test:'hello'},{id:2, userId:'124',test:'world'}];
const members = [{id:'123',firstName:'sam',lastName:'rest', email:'something@a.com'},
 {id:'124',firstName:'tim',lastName:'best', email:'abc@a.com'}];

let result = messages.map(message => {
  let obj = {
    "messageId": message.id,
    "userId": message.userId,
    "test": message.test
  };

  let member = members.find(member => member.id === message.userId);

  if (member) {
    obj.fullName = member.firstName + ' ' + member.lastName;
    obj.email = member.email;
  }

  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rename some values and use a clsoure for destructuring an getting a new property.

```js
var messages = [{ id: 1, userId: '123', test: 'hello' }, { id: 2, userId: '124', test: 'world' }],
    members = [{ id:'123', firstName: 'sam', lastName: 'rest', email:'something@a.com' },  { id: '124', firstName: 'tim', lastName: 'best', email: 'abc@a.com' }],
    result =  messages.map(({ id: messageId, ...message }) => ({
        messageId,
       ...message,
       ... (({ firstName, lastName, email }) => ({ fullName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`, email }))
           (members.find((member) => member.id === message.userId))
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```